# Delta Lake MERGE INTO statement

Tags: apache-spark, delta-lake

I'm trying to run Delta Lake `MERGE INTO`

```
MERGE INTO sessions
USING updates
ON sessions.sessionId = updates.sessionId
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE *
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT *
```

I'm getting an SQL error

```
ParseException: mismatched input 'MERGE' expecting {'(', 'SELECT', 'FROM', 'ADD', 'DESC', 'WITH', 'VALUES', 'CREATE', 'TABLE', 'INSERT', 'DELETE', 'DESCRIBE', 'EXPLAIN', 'SHOW', 'USE', 'DROP', 'ALTER', 'MAP', 'SET', 'RESET', 'START', 'COMMIT', 'ROLLBACK', 'REDUCE', 'REFRESH', 'CLEAR', 'CACHE', 'UNCACHE', 'DFS', 'TRUNCATE', 'ANALYZE', 'LIST', 'REVOKE', 'GRANT', 'LOCK', 'UNLOCK', 'MSCK', 'EXPORT', 'IMPORT', 'LOAD'}(line 2, pos 0)
== SQL ==
MERGE INTO sessions
^^^
USING updates
ON sessions.sessionId = updates.sessionId
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE *
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT *
"
```

I am using `io.delta:delta-core_2.11:0.6.1`
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `merge` SQL support is added in [Delta Lake 0.7.0](https://github.com/delta-io/delta/releases/tag/v0.7.0). You also need to upgrade your Apache Spark to 3.0.0 and enable the integration with Apache Spark DataSourceV2 and Catalog APIs in order to use the new SQL support in Delta Lake 0.7.0. Please check [instructions](https://docs.delta.io/0.7.0/delta-update.html#table-deletes-updates-and-merges) in the Delta Lake docs.