# Insert delta records in master and update existing column value if match found

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a **master** table

```
#+-----------+----------+-------------+
#| Name      | Gender   | date        |
#+-----------+----------+-------------+
#|  Tom      |   M      |  2021-02-15 | 
#|  Bob      |   M      |  2021-03-02 |
#|  Kelly    |   F      |  2021-06-01 |
```

And a **daily**  table , A daily table can have a data with following conditions

1)Totally new records 2)date column updated for existing records

```
#+-----------+----------+-------------+
#| Name      | Gender   | date        |
#+-----------+----------+-------------+
#|  Tom      |   M      |  2021-03-20 | date updated 
#|  suzen    |   F      |  2021-06-10 | new records
```

**expected output** master table should have all the new records coming in daily
plus if any of the name matches with master table then update the new date from daily

```
#+-----------+----------+-------------+
#| Name      | Gender   | date        |
#+-----------+----------+-------------+
#|  Tom      |   M      |  2021-03-20 | date updated form daily
#|  Bob      |   M      |  2021-03-02 |
#|  Kelly    |   F      |  2021-06-01 |
#|  suzen    |   F      |  2021-06-10 | New record
```

For ease, lets take **Name as the unique identifier of both tables**.

there is a one way to to join both of these table on full outer and get the result

```
   select  (case when d.name is null or d.name='' then m.name
            when m.name is null or m.name='' then d.name
            else m.name end) as name,
        (case when d.gender is null or d.gender ='' then m.gender 
            when m.gender is null or m.gender ='' then d.gender 
            else m.gender end) as gender,
         (case when d.date is null or d.date ='' then m.date 
            when m.date is null or m.date ='' then d.date
            else d.date end) as date
    Form master m full outer join daily d on 
    on m.name=d.name
```

What is the way to achieve the expected output in **better and more performant way**

Answer (score 1):

To have a new table (dataframe) based on your criteria, your solution is good.
But if you want to update the master table using the daily table, delta supports upsert into a table using merge:

```
from delta.tables import *

master_table = DeltaTable.forPath(spark, "/path/to/master")
daily_table = DeltaTable.forPath(spark, "/path/to/daily")

master_table.alias("master").merge(
    daily_table.alias("daily"),
    "master.Name = daily.Name") \
  .whenMatchedUpdate(set = { "Gender" : "daily.Gender", "date": "daily.date"} ) \
  .whenNotMatchedInsert(values =
    {
      "Name": "daily.Name",
      "Gender": "daily.Gender",
      "date": "daily.date"
    }
  ) \
  .execute()
```

or using SQL

```
MERGE INTO master
USING daily
ON master.Name = daily.Name
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET master.Gender = daily.Gender, master.date = daily.date
WHEN NOT MATCHED
  THEN INSERT (Name, Gender, date) VALUES (Name, Gender, date)
```

Comment: I have two questions instead of DeltaTable.forPath(spark, "/path/to/master") can I used spark.sql('select * from master') and which sql gives me best performance the one which I have used with outer join or the one which you used with merge and match , can you please help me with the reason, I have read the outer/full join is expensive

Comment: from delta.tables import *
Looks like it need spark 3.0 version onword , can you help with spark version lower than 3

Comment: I am not sure if delta.tables is supported in spark 2.x.x, but I'm sure that you can use the second option (by SQL), so instead of loading the data as a delta table, you can load it as a spark dataframe using `spark.read.format("delta").load("...")`, then you can register the tables as temp views and execute the SQL query which merge the tables... if you have a hive/warehouse metastore, don't need to load the dataframes, you can execute the SQL query directly

Comment: I am getting same exception if I execute sql  "mismatched input 'MERGE' expecting" I found exception post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62900812/delta-lake-merge-into-statement